# Wanted: Elegant validateUserInterfaceItem implementation for protocol composition

Tags: swift, cocoa

I have an `NSOutlineView` with an underlying model composed of Nodes. These Nodes have many different capabilities built up with protocols.

**EDIT** -- to clarify, the capabilities described by each protocol are implemented as protocol defaults in extensions, so currently, subclasses are not having to contain any methods to conform to the protocol.

I have an `NSMenu` that contains actions that might be done on the `Node`s in the view.

I would like to validate the menu items for the currently selected `Node`, but I can't think of a way to do it without writing one massive function on the base class.

The checks I need are not simply Protocol conformance - for example a `Node` that implements an Indentable protocol can not be indented in all circumstances. I need a `canIndent()` to complement the `indent()` method.

In C++, a long time ago, I implemented something similar by building a validation table as a static array on the base class. Subclasses registered their methods at startup. However, when using Swift I can't put expressions at the top level to do this cleanly, and there is no init code at the protocol level.

The only way I can think to do this at the moment is with a method on Node in this form:

```
func validAction(_ action: Selector) -> Bool
{
    switch(action)
    {
    case #selector(indent):
        if self is Indentable {
            return (self as! Indentable).canIndent

        ...
```

**EDIT** -- As Willeke has noted, I could write this on each subclass that conforms to a protocol, but that would involve a lot of repetition.

Ideally, I would build a method on Node of the form:

```
func validAction(_ action: Selector) -> Bool 
{
    if self.responds(to: action) {
        return validations[action].valid
    } 

    return false
}
```

Has anyone done this nicely!?

**EDIT** -- One idea might be to do something with the Selector description to build a validation Selector with a naming convention - e.g. `indent()` -> `indentValid()`

Comment: Are you using bindings and object controllers with your outline view?

Comment: I am not. Would that solve this issue?

Comment: There were a few things that pushed me away from bindings. I need detailed animation control for example.

Comment: See [User Interface Validation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UIValidation/UIValidation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000040-BABFIBIA). Each class validates its actions and calls `super` to validate other actions.

Comment: That's the crux of the issue @Willeke - I have no super, so I can't walk up a hierarchy. I need to broadly check across protocols that might be implemented.

Comment: Protocols can't validate, classes can. Why can't you implement `validAction` in the subclasses?

Comment: Another idea: make `validations` a lazy var and call `self.addValidations`. Override `addValidations` in the subclasses. Instead of a `validAction` method there's a `addValidations` method.

Comment: Thank you @Willeke, that's an interesting idea. I'm afraid I missed a detail in my question (I will edit). I have managed to implement all my actions as protocol defaults, which means that the subclasses are not having to implement anything at the moment, they are just labelled as conforming to each protocol. I could also write any individual action validations as protocol defaults. I am just trying to avoid putting extra code in each subclass that conforms to a protocol.

Comment: Which class is responsible for the validation of the action? Does validation depend on the state of the item?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191160/discussion-between-giles-and-willeke).